# Issue with SSIS Package stored procedure date conversion

Tags: date, stored-procedures, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package based on an existing SSIS package.  In one of the steps I need to pass a time stamp to a stored procedure and save it in the database.

I am not very familiar with SSIS.

I am getting time stamp from a script with this code

Dts.Variables["Date_updated"].Value = DateTime.Now;

Date_updated is defined as DateTime. Under package variables.

This is true for both packages.

I calling a stored procedure and passing the parameter as type date for both packages. Under parameter mapping.

The stored procedure parameter input type is nvarchar(24).

One package passes the value to the stored procedure as Sep 12 2019  2:50PM.

And the value saves without the time stamp which I need.

The other package works correctly as the value is passed to the stored procedure as 2019-09-12 14:53:09.

I can work around the issue by changing the Date_updated a string and the parameter mapping to a string. (And given the input type of the stored procedure that does make sense.)

I do not want to. I want to know what is going and fix the actual issue.

VS 2015.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please edit your post for clarity. I'm having a hard time discerning which steps apply to which packages.Are you saying it's generating the correct date, but in the incorrect format?

Comment: Both packages are exactly

Comment: Thanks for the response.  They are the same.  Same variable type. DATETIME Same variable names.  The scripts that populate the variables are the same. Which is passed via parameter mapping with the same parameter type DATE to the same stored procedure.  But in the stored procedure one is formatted without the time as Sep as 12 2019 2:50PM.  The other is formatted correctly with the time 2019-09-12 14:53:09. The stored procedure input value is nvarchar(24)

Comment: It seems like the issue is the string parameter looking for a datetime. If you are using a datetime in the stored procedure you should change the stored procedure.